# How do I copy over a value from another worksheet depending on the adjacent column?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have two checklists of the same items in a different order in two separate sheets, and I want to only update one. Basically, I have two pages that look like this

[image]

[image]

And I want the? to be automatically replaced with the according to values in the other sheet. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2:E, Sheet1!A2:C, 3, 0)))
```

[image: 0]